# Отправка POST запроса Angular

Tags: http, angular2, angular, angular4

Всем привет. Всё никак не могу разобраться в отправке запроса на ангуляре. Методы GET и DELETE работают отлично. Самая загвоздка в том, что данную строку "тест" через приложение постмен всё отправляется и отлично работает. А вот через Ангуляр нет. Ошибку прикрепил ниже. Заранее спасибо.

```
createNewUser(){
    const myHeaders=new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type':'application/json'});
    const TEST={"firstName":"zczxzxx","lastName":"zxczxcxz","login":"login3374","password":"password33","passwordRepeat":"asdasdasdas"};
    return this.http.post
    ('http://localhost:8080/users',TEST, {headers:myHeaders, })
        .subscribe(
            (val) => {
                console.log("POST call successful value returned in body",
                    val);
            },
            response => {
                console.log("POST call in error", response);
            },
            () => {
                console.log("The POST observable is now completed.");
            });
}
```

Та же функция в POSTMAN
[image: Та же функция в POSTMAN]

Ошибка:
[image: Ошибка]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С Spring помочь особо не смогу ((, но я бы копал в направлении возникновения этой ошибки.

Вот обсуждение похожей ситуации на англоязычной ветке

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56946280/has-been-blocked-by-cors-policy-response-to-preflight-request-doesnt-pass

Comment: Конкретно то что вы скинули мне не помогло. Но благодаря этому стукнуло в голову поменять конфиг корсов и всё зарабатало! Спасибо :)

Comment: Ну вот и отлично )

Answer (score 0):

По всей видимости нужно разрешить cors на стороне сервера. Сервер на NodeJS?

Современные браузеры используют CORS в API-контейнерах, таких как XMLHttpRequest или Fetch, чтобы снизить риски, присущие запросам с других источников.

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Поэтому с postman работает а с браузера нет

Comment: Сервер на Java Spring Boot
Вот настройки корсов на стороне сервера: 
`    
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");   
`
Методы GET и DELETE с браузера работают, а POST нет

Comment: В пустых ковычках знак звёздочки